# Supress output from android activity running from adb shell

Tags: android

Android activity is launched from adb shell by the command **am start -n packagename/.activityname**

When the activity is started it is displaying the status **stating the android activity ...** in the adb shell

How to supress that output into adb shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linux- redirect the output to /dev/null.

```
am start -n packagename/.activityname > /dev/null
```

Comment: Try using > /dev/null 2>&1